# Clear:Both IE6 and up

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser, footer

I have a website I am working on: tinyurl.com/6s4nwnu

I have the whole website other then the menu and the footer in a wrapper div. The footer div has a clear:both on it, that works in every browser but IE (go figure).

I have tried the clear fix, with no luck.

When you resize the browser, the menu disappears as well, and the footer goes to mid-page. Not sure why.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few more issues with the page besides that, and fixing them might fix the rest.  Your text also goes out of frame if the window size is not wide enough to display all the text.  A min-width would help out with that.  It also may help out with your other problems.

Right now your #content sizes don't match up right with the box model for ie8 or lower, so fixing all of that should come first to narrow down where the other issues are coming from.  The DTD would need to be set so that IE uses Quirks Mode, because that's the only way I'm getting the boxes to line up right.  I notice that you've done that, but by doing so, the IE9 design is not as clean as it should be.  Using the [Internet Explorer conditional css tags](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) should help out there.  I'd put in a min-width for all of it so that it doesn't break when your width is not great enough, since that is a problem in Firefox as well.  I tried using IETester to see if it could recreate the ie6 error, but no luck there.  I would put in a min-width on your content, and see if your problems go away.

Comment: Min-width seemed to fix the menu(Sometimes it still goes, but it seems erratic), how would I fix the footer bar. Now it's staying at the bottom of the site(most of the time), but is still above the content.

Comment: Hard to say, but from what I can tell, you may need to define a height to keep the footer from jumping up above content.  Either a static height, or JavaScript to determine the height of the wrapper.  I should have access to actual ie6 tomorrow to see if I can recreate the problem, as it doesn't do it in IETester.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions.

See http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/
Where you can find a detailed list of browser specific hacks to target specific browsers.

Or

You can use Paul Irish's conditional html class.
Which i extended for your case to include "ie" besides the version.

```
 <!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie ie6"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie ie7"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie ie8"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie ie9"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Where you can later target IE like so:

```
.ie{}  // targets all IE's
.ie6{} // targets IE6
.ie7{} // targets IE7 
.ie8{} // targets IE8
.ie9{} // targets IE9
```

http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/